# How to write on multiple lines in a QMessageBox in QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmessagebox

I would like to have in a message box the following lines:

```
name:
surname:
data:
test:
```

After each `:` I'll programmatically fill the line. I would like to ask how can I have this structure in a QMessageBox. It is possible?

I am a beginner in Qt Creator. Currently I learned to do this:

```
QMessageBox noc;
            std::string s= "hello1";
            QString er = s.c_str();
            noc.setText(er);
            noc.exec()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QString str;

str = QString("name: %1\nsurname: %2\ndata: %3").arg(...).arg(...).arg(...);
QMessageBox::information(0, "Title", str);
```

Take a look at [QMessageBox::information()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qmessagebox.html#information) and [QString::arg()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#arg).

Answer (score 2):

just add "\n" at the end of each string...

```
QMessageBox noc;
QString er = tr("name: %1\nsurname: %2\ndata: %3\ntest:%4").arg(...);
noc.setText(er);
noc.exec();
```